# How to reject a call programatically android

Tags: android

Is it possible to reject a call by code in android
please help i have gone through some tutorials but they are not working for me.

Comment: did u give the following permissions   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

Comment: but obvious it is import to give vipin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes dude it it possible try this http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.in/2010/10/blocking-incoming-call-android.html it is working i tried

Comment: hey Sorry to say but it is not working i am doing same as in tutorial

Comment: dude you have to create aidl file for interface

Answer (score 2):

No, AFAIK and AFAITried this is not possible... This was possible in 2.2 and before. after 2.2 they change some security permission or library i dont know. You will find many links saying "its doable and i have tried and its working" and they may be right but it will be before 2.2.... Hope i answer ur question.